# How to declare object of integer list in java class

Tags: java, class

Here is code I want to declare an object of integer list in my class but it is showing error here. How do I add object of list integer to my class?

```
package JavaApplication1;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */

public class Word 
{

    private String path;
    private transient int frequency;
    private List<int> Lpaths;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review M Sach's and my edits, and keep them in mind for next time.

Comment: Java 10 is likely to add support for `List<int>` but for now you need `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `int` as the type parameter for `List`, it has to be an object type. So you need `List<Integer>`.

Comment: here can i declare it with new as   List<Integer> lobj=new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: @UmairNazir: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to declare a generic `List` using a primitive `int` as the type.  This won't work, because only class types which extend `Object` are allowed.  This is the code which achieves what you were trying to do:

```
private List<Integer> Lpaths;
```